# Evaluation of $\int^{2}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $$I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx\;,$$ Now put $x^2=\tan  t\;,$ Then $2xdx = \sec^2 tdt$

So $$I = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2 t}{\sec t \sqrt{\tan t}}dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2 t}}dt$$

Now put $\displaystyle 2t=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta\;,$ Then $dt = -d\theta\;,$ So we get $$I = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}d\theta$$

So $$I = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2 \theta}}d\theta = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int^{\theta}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2 u}}du = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}F\left(\theta\mid 2\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}F\left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-t}{2}\mid 2\right) +\mathcal{C}= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}F\left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-\tan^{-1}x^2}{2}\mid 2\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

Using elliptical integral of first kind, $$F(\phi\mid k^2) = \int^{\phi}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$$

Now How can I calculate $$\int^{2}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$$

Help required, Thanks

Comment: Wait a minute. You found the indefinite integral, but can't substitute the limits?

Comment: To  Yuriy, after substuting limit, I did not understand how can i calculate $F(\frac{\pi}{8}|2)$ and $F(\frac{\pi-2\tan^{-1}(4)}{8}|2)$

Comment: @juantheron In general, those functions are evaluated numerically. For example, $\mathrm{F}\left({\pi \over 8}\mid 2\right) \approx 0.4154$ as
[given here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticF%5BPi%2F8,2%5D).

Comment: http://residuetheorem.com/2015/06/06/adventures-in-integration-university-edition/

Comment: Thanks Ron Gordon for Nice explanation.